# Add polygon as css background

Tags: css

I want to have a div where the upper part has a black background and is a polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 780px, 0 670px). The other part of the background of this div should be white. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you say polygon, do you mean a clip-path polygon?

Maybe something like this?  I made the DIV 1000x1000 arbitrarily.

```css
.polygon-bg 
{   width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}

.polygon-bg::before
{   background-color: Lime;
    content: "";
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 780px, 0 670px);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}



.polygon-bg .content
{   position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="polygon-bg">
    <div class="content">
     <h1>Some text...</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This is nice example of drawing a polygon, but what would be the best way of making it a background to the div? Would we need to put it into a div of its own which would lie behind the main div?

Comment: @AHaworth, Just pot the content in the div.

Comment: @Linux4Life531 yes that would be OK, if you are able to alter the HTML [the question tagged CSS only but I guess they can alter the HTML if it's theirs]- and it's a clearer way of drawing (using clip path) than the background-image way in my answer where juggling the transparent and other color is not immediately obvious.

Comment: I edited the above code.  Clip path will cut off the content, but if you use it as a before element and position it absolutely, it can work.  Just be sure to have any content you might want overlapping it be positioned relatively with a higher z-index.

To make the text more easily visible I changed the bg color to lime, but obviously color adjustments can be made.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple shape like this you could use linear-gradients in an background-image CSS declaration as you can have as many ‘images’ as you like, separated by commas, and each with its own positioning.

Your shape is a rectangle with a triangle beneath. Instead of using different colors to merge into one another we can just use black for both the start and end colors.

So here is the snippet to create a class called polygon which will make the background color of the div white and overlay one black polygon.

```css
.polygon {
     width:400px;/* set these as required */
     height:1024px;
     background:
       linear-gradient(black,black) top/100% 670px, 
       linear-gradient(to bottom left,black 50%,transparent 50%) 0px 670px /100% 110px;
       background-color:white;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<div class="polygon"></div>
```